# Add .so File To Android Studio , Execution failed

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android-studio

I import a project from eclipse to Android Studio. in android studio works fine but no in Android studio.

I load my library here:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

And i have  a folder in  app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/    libopencv_java.so

But  android Studio says.   Execution failed for tast ':app:compileDebugNdk'

which step I need to do?

i only need include one .so file in my proyect.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio, you have to put your .so files inside `jniLibs/(armeabi-v7a|x86|...)` folder if you want them to be included inside your APK.

If you have files under `jni` folder, Android Studio will try to compile your sources using the NDK and an auto-generated Makefile, that's certainly this task that is currently failing with your project.